# Group by in Entity Framework with LINQ not working for me

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have this table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Audit] 
(
    [AuditId] INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Entity]  INT          NOT NULL,
    [UserId]  INT          NOT NULL,
    [Note]    VARCHAR(200) NULL,
    [Date]    DATETIME     NOT NULL,
    [Action]  INT          NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Audit] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AuditId] ASC)
);
```

What I would like to do is to get a report that shows something like this:

```
UserId  Action  Count
---------------------    
user1   Insert  25
user1   Update  30
User1   Delete  45
User2   Insert  99
User2   Update  77
User2   Delete  77
```

I used this LINQ but not sure why it just gives me one user and not the others.  I checked the data and it is a mixture of different userIds.

```
Audits.GroupBy(a => a.Action)
        .Select(a => new { UserId = userId, Action = a.Key, Count = a.Count() })
        .ToList();
```

Does anyone have an idea what might be wrong/

Based on the answer provided by octavioccl I was able to get this:

```
admin2  Insert  798
admin2  Update  640
admin1  Insert  123
admin3  Update  1403
admin2  Delete  11
admin1  Update  41
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to group by those two columns:

```
Audits.GroupBy(a => new{a.UserId, a.Auction})
      .OrderBy(g=>g.Key.UserId).ThenBy(g=>g.Key.Auction)
      .Select(a => new { UserId = a.Key.UserId , Action = a.Key.Auction, Count = a.Count() })
      .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks.  This gives almost what I am looking for but I saw the user1, user2 were mixed up. I added an example to the end of my question so you could see what it looks like.  Is there a way I could order these?

Comment: @Anne: Just add an `OrderBy()` and `ThenBy()` to get it to order by username first, then by action.

Comment: Thanks @StriplingWarrior for your recomendation